# Conditional expectation with Poisson processes and continuous uniform distribution.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, poisson-process

$N$ is a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$. We have arrival times $T_{1}, T_{2}, \ldots, T_{N},$  independent uniform distributed events in [0,1]. Let $T=\min \left\{T_{1}, T_{2}, \ldots, T_{N}\right\}$. I'm struggling with the following questions:

1- $P(T>t \mid N=n)$ for every $t \in[0,1]$.

2- $E[T \mid N=n]=\frac{1}{n+1}$ ,  $E[T \mid N]$

3- $E[T]$

I didn't find much examples about the conditional expectation with Poisson processes and continuous uniform distribution.

Comment: What is meant by $T_N$? $N$ denotes the entire process $\{N(t): t\geqslant 0\}$, not a nonnegative integer-valued random variable (which would make more sense).

Comment: $N$ is the number of buses which pass from the college the next hour, and $T_{1}, T_{2}, \ldots, T_{N}$ the times when they passed.

Comment: there is no notation such as ${N(t): t\geqslant 0\}$ in the exercise

Comment: Hint: The minimum of $n$ uniform random variables on $[0,1]$ is a Beta distribution. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Comment: Thank you for sharing your hint. But I still have a problem, since the beta distribution is a family of continuous probability distributions defined on the interval $[0, 1]$, and I only know the formulation of the conditional expectation of two variables with the same type. However, here $N$ is discrete, and $T$ is continuous !